# I am trying to get excel to automatically insert date when another cell is changed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date

I have tried the following:

```
=IF(A1<>"",IF(B1<>"",B1,NOW()),"").
```

and enabled iterative calculation.

It still updates to the time when I open the spreadsheet. This sheet is being used by multiple users some on Excel 2010, others on 2013.

I have tried using VBA as well and it is not working.

Comment: Given that excel will keep changing the date on each calculation means that excel formulas is never going to work and VBA is going to be the only way to ensure that this works. But for us to help you with VBA macro's, we do need to see your macro first. Alternatively, you can make the user enter the date themselves.

Comment: Look into the [worksheet change event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Answer (score 0):

If the cell you want to monitor is in A column and the date is in B column then follow this:

Go to FORMULAS tab and click on Define Name.
[image: Define Name]

--

Then at name put any name - in my example is "DateCell".
Select the sheet where you want it to take effect - in my example Sheet1.
At refers to put the following formula:

```
=IF(A1:A<>"",IF(B1:B="",Now(),B1:B),"")
```

[image: Defining Name and Formula]

After doing this, right click at worksheet tab and click at View Code and then paste the below vba code (worksheet change event as suggested by cybernetic.nomad)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim DateCell As Range
    Set DateCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
    If DateCell.Value = "" Then
        DateCell.Value = Date
    Else
        DateCell.Value = Date
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thank you the time is still updating itself whenever the sheet is opened

Comment: Did you put formulas in cells in B columns? This column should be empty